# How can I make a button in Javascript that clears two textareas?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code so far:

```js
function addtext() {
  var newtext = document.myform.inputtext.value;
  document.myform.outputtext.value += newtext;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">&nbsp;
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><textarea name="inputtext"></textarea></td>
        <td>
          <p>
            <br />
            <input onclick="addtext();" type="button" value="Strip HTML Formatting" />
          </p>
        </td>
        <td><textarea readonly name="outputtext"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Now I want to add a button that clears the two textareas.
Where should I be putting the JavaScript for that, and what should it say?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to clear both `textarea`s when the button is clicked? Or Copy the text from first `textarea` to the next one?

Comment: And since you have `<textarea readonly name="outputtext"></textarea>` the second `textarea` is always going to be empty anyway. So I don't get the point of emptying both `textarea`s.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py It already copies one to the other. What I want a new button to do is to clear both of them

Comment: Step 1) Make clicking on a button call a function. Step 2) Write a function that clears a text area. Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the reset type attribute:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

---

**Code snippet:**

```js
function addtext() {
  var newtext = document.myform.inputtext.value;
  document.myform.outputtext.value += newtext;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">&nbsp;
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td><textarea name="inputtext"></textarea></td>
      <td>
        <input onclick="addtext()" type="button" value="Strip HTML Formatting" /><br />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
      </td>
      <td><textarea readonly name="outputtext"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

This resets all form values to their default values.

---

If you have other textareas besides these and you only want to empty these two, you should create another button that links to a function that empties the values:

**HTML**:

```
<input onclick="emptyText()" type="button" value="Clear fields" />
```

**JS:**

```
function emptyText() {
    document.myform.inputtext.value = "";
    document.myform.outputtext.value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/guoyh1om/1/)

#### HTML:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea name="inputtext"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <br />
          <input type="button" value="Strip HTML Formatting" />
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="inputtext" readonly></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>Empty</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var removeBtn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var copyBtn = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
copyBtn.onclick = function () {
    var inpt = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
    document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[1].value = inpt;
}
removeBtn.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value = "";
    document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[1].value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### OPTION 1:

Use a reset type input-button:

```js
function addtext() {
  var newtext = document.myform.inputtext.value;
  document.myform.outputtext.value += newtext;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">&nbsp;
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td><textarea name="inputtext"></textarea></td>
      <td>
        <input onclick="addtext()" type="button" value="Strip HTML Formatting" /><br />
        <input type="reset" value="Clear fields" />   <!--THIS LINE-->
      </td>
      <td><textarea readonly name="outputtext"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

- This resets all form values to their default values.

---

### OPTION 2:

If you have other textareas besides these and you only want to empty these two, you should create another button that links to a function that empties the values:

```js
function addtext() {
  var newtext = document.myform.inputtext.value;
  document.myform.outputtext.value += newtext;
}

function clearFields() {
    document.myform.inputtext.value = "";
    document.myform.outputtext.value = "";
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">&nbsp;
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td><textarea name="inputtext"></textarea></td>
      <td>
        <input onclick="addtext()" type="button" value="Strip HTML Formatting" /><br />
        <input onclick="clearFields()" type="button" value="Clear fields" />   <!--THIS LINE-->
      </td>
      <td><textarea readonly name="outputtext"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

- This literally sets the values of the two textareas to 'empty'.